# How to convert .rank into an integer value?

Tags: java, loops

Trying to create a Blackjack game in Java and cannot understand how to obtain a numerical value from the array thing.

Here's my code for the deck of cards:

```
//Represent a playing card
public class Card
{
    //Instance variables:
    int suit; //0=clubs, 1=diamonds, 2=hearts, 3=spades
    int rank; //1=ace, 2=2,..., 10=10, 11=J, 12=Q, 13=K

    //Constructor:
    public Card (int theSuit, int theRank)
    {
        suit = theSuit;
        rank = theRank;
    }

    //Print the card in a human-readable form:
    public void printCard()
    {
        String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
        String[] ranks = {"narf", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
            "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
        System.out.print(ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit]);
    }
}
```

See I've used Card cardOne = deck.cards[(int) (Math.random() * 52)]; to obtain the first and second cards for the player to see, but I'm struggling to figure out how to save the value of the card (4 for a 4 of Hearts, 10 for a Jack of Spades, etc.) as an integer value to use to determine how many points the player?

Sorry, if this is confusing, English is not my first language.

Thanks in advance!

-John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an `int[]` array that has points values where the indexes line up with the `ranks` array.

```
String[] ranks = {"narf", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
            "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
int[] points = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
            8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10};
```

Then, when your random number generates an `int` value (let's call it `index`), you can just do:

```
String rank = ranks[index];
int numberOfPoints = points[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an integer `n` from 0 to 51 inclusive, you can convert it to two numbers in the 0-3 and 0-12 range like this:

```
suit = n / 13;       // will be in range 0 to 3
rank = n % 13;       // will be in range 0 to 12
```

or

```
rank = n / 4;        // will be in range 0 to 12
suit = n % 4;        // will be in range 0 to 3
```

Unless you're planning on doing something else with `n`, it probably doesn't matter which one of these you choose.  If you do plan to use `n` to represent a card, you'll have to decide whether you want the order to be club-ace, diamond-ace, heart-ace, spade-ace, club-2, diamond-2, etc. ... or club-ace, club-2, club-3, club-4 ... club-king, diamond-ace, diamond-2, ...